Where can I get information about error codes Entity Framework?
There is an operation that is very often used by many users, this is adding a certain string to a column that does not allow adding duplicate values, due to the fact that the operation is often used. I transferred the responsibility of checking for the uniqueness of the string to the database, which handles this well and returns if the string is repeated HResult -2146233087, I would like to read the documentation on this error code to be sure that this code will not come from another database error
I tried looking for Microsoft documentation, but I couldn't find it.

EF doesn't use error codes. The ADO.NET SQL Server driver may include a code in a detailed exception. What is the actual error you get?

Thats an HResult in its decimal notation. Its easier when viewed in standard hex. Your HResult translated to COR_E_SYSTEM. That one is absolutely generic and you have to dig deeper on the exception in the hopes for more details.

If you have setup an unique constraint on that column, you can always check that the name you gave that constraint is in the error

I don’t think you want to look at HRESULT. What you’re probably looking for is something like this:
try
{
    //…
}
catch (SqlException x) when (x.Number == 2601 || x.Number == 2627)
{
    //2601: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object '%.*ls' with
    //      unique index '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.
    //2627: Violation of %ls constraint '%.*ls'. Cannot insert duplicate
    //      key in object '%.*ls'. The duplicate key value is %ls.
}

See https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors-2000-to-2999 for all the error codes.
Edit: Actually, with EF you’ll have to check the InnerException, so it’s something like this if you still want to cram it in the when:
catch (DbUpdateException x) when (x.InnerException is SqlException inner && (inner.Number == 2627 || inner.Number == 2601))

